# Django form for model referenced by foreign keys

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am creating a quiz application in django.  As of right now, I have two models, Question and Answer.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    video_ref = models.ForeignKey('Video')

class Answer(models.Model):
    question_ref = models.ForeignKey('Question') 
    answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    correct = models.BooleanField()
```

This setup allows me to have variable numbers of potential answers to every question with a possibility of multiple correct answers.

I want to create a form model for a Question such that every Answer that points to the Question is part of the form.  How can this be done?

Comment: Is it a [model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/) or a [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/) ?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to achieve here, if it's a quiz app, then you should have choices, not answers! i think what you want in admin is to create a question with a set of choices, and let the user choose the answer in a form. if that is the case, it's a poll app and you can find in django tutorials.

Comment: Do you want this in the stock admin, or in your custom views?

Comment: I meant Answer to be a possible answer, sorry for the confusion.  The polls app tutorial was extremely helpful, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as follow:

**forms.py**

```py
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    answers = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Question.answer_set.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
```

Using `forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField` and the widget `forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple` django will render the form with checkbox for you.